# How to validate using Paypal API v2 in client side

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

We currently using checkout.js from paypal when doing payments, everything works well and we want now to upgrade to v2 of paypal api.

below is our code using checkout.js
https://jsfiddle.net/hxm0cjbp/

```
paypal.Button.render({
    style: {
        // style here
    },
    env: variable_here,
    client: {
        sandbox: variable_here,
        production: variable_here
    },
    commit: true,
    validate: function (actions) {
        // problem occur from here in v2
        // by using actions.disable();
        functionToDisableButtonIfValidationFail();
    },
    onClick: function () {
        // more functions here
    },
    payment: function (data, actions) {
        // more functions here
    },
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        // more functions here
    }
}, '#selector_here');
```

below is our new code using v2.
https://jsfiddle.net/sk3rpme5/

```
paypal.Buttons({
   validate: function(){
      // problem occur from here
      // actions.disable() is not recognize anymore
      functionToDisableButtonIfValidationFail();
   },
   createOrder: function() {
      // function here
   }
}).render('#selector_here');
```

the error starts in validate method.
In using v1, when clicking the paypal button. If validation fails, it will show form errors. In v2, when clicking the paypal button. The paypal redirect page still shows and the form errors too. We would like to work it out like v1, show only the paypal page if validation is correct. When checking the SDK, it looks like `validate` was removed.

Comment: _“(Sorry if I use snippets, SO is showing me errors when putting the code here)”_ - then fix whatever those errors are telling you is wrong, instead of using that as a cheap excuse to not properly provide all necessary information _inside_ the question, as _required_.

Comment: "instead of using that as a cheap excuse". Thank you for your nice response @04FS. I tried but I really can't post with those code. Could you please try to edit it? Thank you Sir.

Comment: Thnak you so much sir @04FS